# Is there any way to enforce synchronous destruction within the execution thread for a COM pointer object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, com

I know that when you create and release a CComPtr class the reference is increased and decreased. When reference gets to 0, the smart COM pointer is destructed.

I am not very sure how COM works regarding concurrency. If I reset/release my CComPtr holding the last reference, do I have a way to fully guarantee that in the next loc the destructor has been fully executed?

I want to know if decreasing the reference and calling the destructor will happen within the same thread that I am resetting the last com pointer. I heard that it is usually some kind of COM thread the one that actually takes care of this. If this is the case, is there any way to synchronize the COM destruction with your main working thread?

Comment: *"When reference gets to 0, the smart COM pointer is destructed."* is not accurate. ATL::CComPtr is a wrapper for scope-managing calls to AddRef (on assignment), Release (on reset, assignment, and falling out of scope), and interface member access. It doesn't actually "destroy" *anything*. If the Release call (either by reset or destruction) sends the objects reference count to zero, the object *self-destructs*. And all of those calls (to AddRef, Release, etc) happen object-side on the thread matching the *apartment model* you're using.

Comment: As a client of a COM object, this shouldn't be your problem, that's the purpose of COM threading models: handle concurrency. Well, if everyone behaves the way it says it's supposed to behave. Don't confuse a smart pointer (CComPtr, which is an optional programming facility) and COM itself.

Comment: Your CComPtr is a client to the COM object.  If the client behaves properly, the COM object will properly manage its own 'life'.  If the COM object is used by multiple clients, and they all properly connect and disconnect from the COM object (AddRef and Release properly), the COM object will instantiate and destroy itself properly, without the need of the client (you) to be concerned about it.  If your concern is to force the COM object to stay alive, you must attach a client and keep it open by keeping the client alive.

Answer (score 0):

Since setting the smart pointer to `nullptr` indirectly calls `IUnknown::Release()`, it's just another function call, so it depends on the current model (see [CoInitializeEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex)).

If it's MTA, releasing occurs in the thread you call it. If it's STA, releasing is serialized. The point of STA is to avoid manual synchronization.

More about COM appartments [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/com/processes--threads--and-apartments).